# winston3-kafka library used for sending logs from node app to kafka not working

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, winston

I am trying to send my Winston logs messages to Kafka, using winston transport. I found this library to help me out since my Winston version is 3.X so many of the 2.X versions do not work.

https://github.com/aidtechnology/winston3-kafka

Here is the example I am trying to use.

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.transports.Kafka = require('winston3-kafka');


var options = {
  topic: 'logs',
  clientOptions: {
  kafkaHost: {'localhost:9092'}  // We connect directly to Kafka, rather than Zookeeper
  }
};

winston.add(new winston.transports.Kafka(options));
```

The following error I get is.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Not sure why this syntax error is occurring. I am copying and pasting from the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

**kafkaHost: 'localhost:9092'**

instead of:

**kafkaHost: {'localhost:9092'}**

So, yes, you have a syntax error.

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.transports.Kafka = require('winston3-kafka');


var options = {
  topic: 'logs',
  clientOptions: {
  kafkaHost: 'localhost:9092'  // We connect directly to Kafka, rather than Zookeeper
  }
};
```

;)

Comment: Yes, now it works! I was just confused since it's a bit odd for a usage example to have an error in it! I was also wondering how it should be structured if we have multiple kafka hosts? i.ie localhost:9092 and localhost:9093

Comment: Maybe you can use an array: **kafkaHost: ['localhost:9092', 'localhost:9093']** ;)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use Zookeeper. Zookeeper will ensure you to connect to the right server, and if you add more kafkas you dont need to deploy your services again.